# Basic LISP recursion, enumerate values greater than 3

Tags: recursion, lisp, clisp

I need a recursive LISP function that enumerates the number of elements in any list of numbers > 3. I'm not allowed to use lets, loops or whiles and can only use basic CAR, CDR, SETQ, COND, CONS, APPEND, PROGN, LIST...

This is my attempt at the function:

```
(defun foo (lst) 
  (COND ((null lst) lst) 
    (T (IF (> (CAR lst) 3) 
      (1+ (foo (CDR lst)))
      (foo (CDR lst)) ) ) ) )
```

The function call:

```
(foo '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is pretty close to correct, just a small mistake in the base case:

For the empty list you return the empty list. So if you have the list `(6)`, you add 6 to `foo` of the empty list, which is the empty list. That does not work because you can't add a number to a list.

You can easily fix it by making `foo` return `0` instead of `lst` when `lst` is empty.

As a style note: Mixing `cond` and `if` like this, seems a bit redundant. I would write it like this, using only `cond` instead:

```
(defun foo (lst) 
  (cond
    ((null lst)
      0)
    ((> (car lst) 3) 
      (1+ (foo (cdr lst))))
    (T
      (foo (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: I did not know cond could work that way. All of the online resources are scattered about the internet and not easy to comprehend...

Comment: The best on-line resource for common lisp is (probably) "The HyperSpec" ( http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/ ) and is close to the most comprehensive description of CL.

Answer (score 5):

Some stylistic points:

- There's no need to put some Lisp built-ins in uppercase. It's not 1958 anymore!
- But if you *are* going to put built-ins in uppercase, why not `DEFUN` and `NULL`?
- You have an `if` inside the last branch of your `cond`. This is redundant. Since the purpose of `cond` is testing conditions, why not use it?
- There's no need to space out your closing parentheses like that. No-one counts parentheses these days, we have parenthesis-matching editors.
- Lisp has separate namespaces for functions and values, so you don't have to call your argument `lst` to avoid conflicting with the built-in function `list`.

If you were programming this for real, of course you'd use [`count-if`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_countc.htm):

```
(count-if #'(lambda (x) (> x 3)) '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6))
    ==> 3
```

Comment: Sorry about the stylistic issues (first program)... perhaps my professor learned LISP in 1958--I chuckled though. I believe "count-if" is outside the scope of the functions we're allowed to use.

Answer (score 0):

One save you can have on duplication of the recursive call:

```
(defun foo (l)
  (if (null l) 0               ; if list is empty, return 0
    (+ (if (> (car l) 3) 1 0)  ; else +1 if condition is satisfactory
      (foo (cdr l)))))         ; plus the result from the rest
```